# tensorflow/C++: when (not) to call Session.Close()?

Tags: tensorflow

Looking at the definition of `Session` I see that [its destructor is empty](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/294442996b2aeff00b1bfdc7e7169f7cb35bbf3d/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/session.cc#L27), in particular it does not call `Close()`. It means that we need to manually call this function before the object gets destroyed.

I was wondering why that is the case. If this function needs to be called every time before the object is destroyed, I suppose it would have been added to the destructor to avoid potential leaks. Therefore I suppose there are situations where `Close()` should not be called, but what are they?

Another way of asking the same question is, what problems would I face if I wrap a `Session` in an object that would call `Close()` upon destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of `Close` allows for error information to be returned to the caller.

`Session` is an interface which has multiple implementations. In particular, when using a distributed setup (such as in [`grpc_session.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_session.cc#L308)) `Close` will attempt to clean up resources in other processes. The return value of `Close` provides an opportunity to be notified of and act on any failures. (FWIW, when not using a distributed setup, the implementation in [`direct_session.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L1363) is typically used, and that never returns an error). This also means that `Close` can be expensive (e.g., blocking till the request is sent over the network and a response is received), which may not be something you'd want to wait for in some cases (e.g., when shutting down the application)

If your application won't be acting on such failures, then I don't believe writing a wrapper session that `Close()`s on destruction would be a problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this is basically because `Close` can signal errors and that a destructor should not that it is not called by `~Session()`?

Comment: I didn't fully follow your follow up question, but yeah, separating `Close` out from the destructor allows: (1) error signaling, (2) avoiding a blocking call (e.g., waiting for the response to a network request) when not needed.

Comment: Note that [`direct_session.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L281) _does_ close the session on destruction.